# Custom Page Templates in WordPress to show Content in specific layout

Tags: wordpress, templates, layout, content-management-system, custom-post-type

I want to create a custom page template in WordPress which shows Image Slideshow and then a video below it and finally some text - till now what I am able to do is play with sidebar, footer, header.

I can either remove them or keep them in my custom page templates but what I want to do is play with the page contents.

The Admin user should be able to see these sections in the Page Editor (WYSIWYG) when they choose the Template from the drop-down, so that they can accordingly add the correct content in correct place holders

Something like the attached screen-shot is showing

### [image]

Is this possible in WordPress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! It's possible to implement this! you can use https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431 or https://wordpress.org/plugins/siteorigin-panels/ plugin.

The first plugin allows you to create different page layout and save it. It also allows admin to choose page layout that admin has saved previously.

The second page builder plugin allows you to create template same way and allows admin to clone one page layout to another one.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I would suggest site-origin as it fulfil all basic requirement and also it is free.